Bool path argument from swagger UI not found in the request
I have a FastAPI endpoint:
@router.post("/")
def create_vacation(
        request: fastapi.Request,
        paid: bool = False,
) -> None:
    print(request.url, paid)

In the swagger, the url showed is:
http://127.0.0.1:880/vacation/?paid=true

and the cURL cmd:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:880/vacation/?paid=true' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -d ''

which result in:
http://127.0.0.1:880/vacation/?paid=true True

But when using the swagger UI, the print(request.url, paid) shows:
http://127.0.0.1:880/vacation/ False

I use FastAPI for years, and this is still a first for me. Any clue?
I use the latest version of fastapi and pydantic (0.113.0 and 2.9.0).
Here is a minimal reproducible example:
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(
    title="Text",
)


@app.post("/")
def create_vacation(
        paid: bool,
):
    print(paid)

Then using swagger UI and selecting true or false in the dropdown:

We get this response:
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "missing",
      "loc": [
        "query",
        "paid"
      ],
      "msg": "Field required",
      "input": null
    }
  ]
}


When the fastapi app is running, your can go to the /docs and use a UI to test the API (alongside documentation).

mybad, I fix it

I tried your code in Swagger UI and it works well. I can see http://127.0.0.1:880/vacation/ False only if I don't choose the value  for paid parameter. In this case Swagger doesn't send this parameter and I see that output (but it's expected result)

if I remove the default param, there is a validation error, 422, with details: "missing field". are you using the same versions as me ?

I didn't remove default param. I just didn't choose its value from the dropdown menu in Swagger. By default - value is selected and Swagger doesn't include this parameter in request. It sends http://127.0.0.1:880/vacation/ (without any query params)

I added the [mre]. The issue is that selecting any value in swagger ui doesn't seems to have any effect.

It looks like the request did not recognize the query parameter ?paid.
Did you see in Swagger under the parameter the (query)
You can try using Annotated with Query it might help resolve the issue
from fastapi import Request, Query
from typing import Annotated

@router.post("/")
def create_vacation(
        request: Request,
        paid: Annotated[bool, Query()] = False,
) -> None:
    print(request.url, paid)


but you saw the curl command and its effects. Why Swagger UI generate a successful command but in action leads to an error ?
